# How to get the index of all elements which are NaN in an array in python?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, indexing

I have an array

```
   [     nan,      nan,      nan,  1633.32,  1661.24,     0.  ],
   [     nan,      nan,      nan,  2885.94,  3264.09,     0.  ],
   [  605.48,      nan,   599.27,   664.47,   670.68,     0.  ],
   [     nan,      nan,      nan,   874.59,   783.86,     0.  ],
   [ 1596.01,      nan,  1469.77,  1731.26,  1514.86,     0.  ]]
```

Is there any way to know the index (row,column) of the elements which are "nan"

Comment: Hi Juhi, what did you try? What was your problem?

Comment: @MarcusMüller My problem is to get the row,column index from an array wherever it's value is "nan"/null, I have been following what others are doing. I cam across the list comprehension: 
indices = [i for i, x in enumerate(my_list) if x == "nan"] 
but as it's for list it is giving just the column index, I wanted to do it on an array, so I need both the row and column index number.

Comment: `from math import isnan; [(r, c) for r, row in enumerate(data) for c, item in enumerate(row) if isnan(item)]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution using `np.isnan` and `np.argwhere` functions combination from `numpy` module:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([[     np.NaN,      np.NaN,      np.NaN,  1633.32,  1661.24,     0.  ],
   [     np.NaN,      np.NaN,      np.NaN,  2885.94,  3264.09,     0.  ],
   [  605.48,      np.NaN,   599.27,   664.47,   670.68,     0.  ],
   [     np.NaN,      np.NaN,      np.NaN,   874.59,   783.86,     0.  ],
   [ 1596.01,      np.NaN,  1469.77,  1731.26,  1514.86,     0.  ]])

print(np.argwhere(np.isnan(arr)))
```

The output:

```
[[0 0]
 [0 1]
 [0 2]
 [1 0]
 [1 1]
 [1 2]
 [2 1]
 [3 0]
 [3 1]
 [3 2]
 [4 1]]
```